# AWS Step functions: how to append a key-value pair to the input json with jsonpath?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, jsonpath, aws-step-functions

As per the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-inputpath-params.html) of AWS Step Functions, you can use the JSON path syntax in the **Parameters** transformation to create a collection of key-value pairs that are passed as input. Given the following input:

```
{
  "comment": "Example for Parameters.",
  "product": {
    "details": {
       "color": "blue",
       "size": "small",
       "material": "cotton"
    },
    "availability": "in stock",
    "sku": "2317",
    "cost": "$23"
  }
}
```

I'd like to transform it this way:

```
{
  "foo": "My new value",
  "comment": "Example for Parameters.",
  "product": {
    "details": {
       "color": "blue",
       "size": "small",
       "material": "cotton"
    },
    "availability": "in stock",
    "sku": "2317",
    "cost": "$23"
  }
}
```

A way to do it can be the following:

```
{
  "foo": "My new value",
  "comment.$": "$.comment",
  "product.$": "$.product"      
}
```

Is there a way to obtain the same result with a kind of "apppend operation", without explicitly referencing the other parts of the JSON that aren't changed at all (i.e., `comment.$` and `product.$`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**GIVEN** the [Pass](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-pass-state.html) state:

```json
{
  "Comment": "Append a new key-value pair",
  "StartAt": "AppendFoo",
  "States": {
    "AppendFoo": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Result": "My new value",
      "ResultPath": "$.foo",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

**WHEN** the OP input is passed,

**THEN** the expected output is produced.  The `Result` is inserted at `ResultPath`.  Note that `Result` must be a literal value (no `.$` substitutions allowed), but need not be a string.  See the [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-pass-state.html#pass-state-example) in the docs.